# Rich Text Editor for Flex 4 that provides link

Tags: apache-flex, rich-text-editor

I have built a rich Text Editor for Flex 4 using the instruction in the following link: 
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/24/creating-a-simple-text-editor-using-the-spark-textarea-control-in-flex-4/

it works great. I want to be able to add link to it (user selecting text to link it to external web page). How do I do that?

I'm open for other suggestions to implement Rich Text Editor with link support if you have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the one built in Adobe - http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/demos/ - maybe it can help you.
The source code should be here: http://blogs.adobe.com/tlf/2009/12/new-and-updated-tlf-samples.html

Comment: The html link is crashed